# Changing a Google visualization chart object

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I'm currently using `ChartWrapper` and `ControlWrapper` to develop
some utilities in a project I have been working on.
Let me use this example from Controls and Dashboards from the example:

```
var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         'chartType': 'PieChart',
         'containerId': 'chart_div',
         'options': {
           'width': 300,
           'height': 300,
           'pieSliceText': 'value',
           'legend': 'right'
         }
       });
```

I know `pieChart` is of the type `ChartWrapper`, but I'm using a `PieChart`
object to draw the chart. Now, how do I do to set up the options of
the `PieChart` object, and not of the `ChartWrapper`?
I tried to use `getChart`, but that always returned me null. I suppose
`ChartWrapper` has an object of the type `PieChart`. If somehow I could
access that object, so I could set up some options to fulfil my
needs.
Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [getChart documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject), which probably explains why you're getting null:

> This will return null until after you have called draw() on the ChartWrapper object, and it throws a ready event.

If you want to set the options, you can just use set them directly on the *ChartWrapper* object.

```
pieChart.setOption("width", 400);
```

Or you can set all the options from scratch:

```
pieChart.setOptions( {
       'width': 300,
       'height': 300,
       'pieSliceText': 'value',
       'legend': 'right'
     } );
```

Comment: Ok, I got that. In my case, I want to change the properties of the 'PieChart' object I've declared.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart
If I want, for example, to set the 3D property:
is3D  boolean  false  If set to true, displays a three-dimensional chart.

Should I do in the same fashion as you've said?

Comment: @philippe Yes, same way.  pieChart.setOption("is3D", true);

Comment: One more question, how do I do to disable the legend in each item of the pie chart?

Comment: @philippe wouldn't that just be *pieChart.setOption("legend", "none")* ?

Comment: I'm working on a BubbleChart. So each "bubble" has a small title (legend) on top of the bubble. I would like to disable that, and only display the bubble itself, and if the user want, by selecting that particular bubble he would be able to see the info associated with the bubble.

Comment: I would like to know how to not show that "title" or legend on the bubble